# Email text validator

Tags: php, design-patterns, validation, email

I'm using this pattern for the first time and wanted to check if this is the correct implementation.

**class.validator.strategy.php**

```
abstract class ValidatorStrategy
{
    abstract public function check( $name, $val );

}
```

**class.text.validator.php**

```
class TextValidator extends ValidatorStrategy
{

    public function check( $name, $val )
    {
         //logic here
    }
}
```

**class.number.validator.php**

```
class NumberValidator extends ValidatorStrategy
{

    public function check( $name, $val )
    {
         //logic here
    }
}
```

**class.validator.php**

```
include('validator.strategy.php');
include('class.text.validator.php');
include('class.number.validator.php');
include('class.email.validator.php');

class Validator
{

    //holds strategy object
    protected $validatorStrategy = array();

    //holds form field
    protected $fields = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validatorStrategy[ 'text' ] = new TextValidator();
        $this->validatorStrategy[ 'number' ] = new NumberValidator();
        $this->validatorStrategy[ 'email' ] = new EmailValidator();
    }

    public function ruleForTextField( $name, $value )
    {
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'value' ] = $value;
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'type' ] = 'text';
    }

    public function ruleForNumbertField( $name, $value )
    {
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'value' ] = $value;
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'type' ] = 'number';
    }

    public function ruleForEmailField( $name, $value )
    {
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'value' ] = $value;
        $this->fields[ $name ][ 'type' ] = 'email';

    }

    public function isValidate()
    {
        $status = 0;

        foreach ( $this->fields as $key => $val )
        {
            if ( !$this->validatorStrategy[ $val[ 'type' ] ]->check( $key, $val ) )
            {
                $status++;
            }

        if ( $status == 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**Uses:**

```
$validator = new Validator();
$validator->ruleForTextField('username', $_POST['username'] );
$validator->ruleForNumberField('age', $_POST['age'] );
$validator->ruleForEmailField('email', $_POST['email'] );

if($validator->isValidate())
{
    echo 'validated';
}
else
{
   echo 'fail validation';
}
```

Inside the `isValidate()` method, it iterate against all validator strategy and perform appropriate logic.

Is this is the correct way to use this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is really a strategy pattern: you never rely on the `ValidatorStrategy` interface, there is no real choice of a strategy (there are direct calls to `Validator` methods) and you cannot add another strategy without braking your context object (`Validator` class).

What you can do is refactor `Validator` to inject a `ValidatorStrategy` instance for each field to validate. Let call this modified class `FormValidator` (a `Validator` instance validates one field only) and see how it can be implemented:

```
class FormValidator
{
  /**
   * @var array of StrategyValidator
   */
  protected $validators;

  /**
   *
   * @param string $name
   * @param ValidatorStrategy $strategy 
   */
  public function addValidator($name, ValidatorStrategy $strategy)
  {
    $this->validators[$name] = $strategy;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param array $form 
   */
  public function isValid($form)
  {
    foreach ($this->validators as $name => $validator)
    {
      if (!$validator->isValid($form[$name]))
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}

$formValidator = new FormValidator();
$formValidator->addValidator('username', new TextValidator());
$formValidator->addValidator('age', new NumberValidator());
$formValidator->addValidator('email', new EmailValidator());

// Now you can reuse $formValidator where you want
$values = array(
  'username'  => $_POST['username'],
  'age'       => $_POST['age'],
  'email'     => $_POST['email'],
);

if($formValidator->isValid($values))
{
    echo 'validated';
}
else
{
   echo 'fail validation';
}
```

Some advices:

- John Kraft's naming advices are excellent, you should follow them: a method starting with is*, has* returns a boolean, methods starting with get* and set* are accessors, etc.
- Always take a moment to think about you classes role, and deduce their name from it
- When manipulating booleans, use boolean vars ($status)
- When using `new Myclass()` in a class method, ask yourself if you are not closing the classes to future evolution, especially if MyClass implements an interface: this is a sign that the class can vary and we should rely on the interface instead (see [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection))

This last advice is illustrated by the method `addValidator()` in my example.

Comment: thx for ur explaination, it really help

Answer (score 4):

No, strategy pattern relies on an interface to allow composition to determine functionality at run time.  Notice that it is easier to extend with new speaking functionality; and can be used to execute at run time.  Here you are just using the array of the interface instantiations to do multiple validations.

I.E.

Interface for the pattern

```
public interface Speak {
  public void execute();
}
```

Implementations of the pattern

```
public class Quack extends Speak {
  public void execute() { /* Quack */ }
}

public class Bark extends Speak {
  public void execute() { /* bark */ }
}
```

Class that uses the strategy

```
public Animal {
  private Speak _speak;
  public Animal(Speak s) { _speak = s; }
}
```

Example usage

```
main() {
  new Animal(new Bark()); /* creates animal that barks */
  new Animal(new Quack()); /* creates animal that quacks */
}
```

Comment: @Suroot - Your way is the normative way of using a strategy pattern, but the OPs solution is very interesting, in that he can easily extend what he can validate by just implementing his interface and adding it to his array, so, he isn't having multiple classes changing what they are doing, but the basic concept of what he is doing is still present.

Comment: His use is more of a lookup style pattern; I'm not sure if there is a design pattern already created for this; but it does not appear to be strategy.  Strategy has one interface and multiple instantiations of that interface followed by one or more classes that contain ONE of those instantiations to give the illusion that the class is changing implementation at run time.

Comment: @Suroot yes i can implement classic strategy pattern but that will force my application code to instantiate all related class.Let say i need to validate 4 type of validation, my application code need to instantiate 4 time validator class...i dont want to force this in my application code..thats why my code en up like that

Comment: @suroot see update, is that more like strategy pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I don't write php, so please bear with me; but I don't care for the isValidate method.  In pseudo-code... I usually write something like

```
foreach(var validator in validatorCollection)
    if validator->Check = false
        return false

return true
```

Also, some of the method names are a bit unclear.  A list of names I'd prefer to see...

- IsValid rather than Check
- IsValid rather than IsValidate

Additionally, I think your example is a poor one for the usage of the strategy pattern, but I'm assuming that's because it is a simple sample problem.

As and example, we use the strategy pattern to determine shipping methods for packages.  We have a validator for UPS, and a validator for USPS, and a validator for FedEx. We pass a package object to each of the validators to determine eligibility.  Each of those validators has a list of rules (weight, height, hazardous materials, etc) to determine if that package can be shipped that method.

```
ListOfCarriers result
ListOfCarriers carriers
foreach(carrier in carriers)
    if(carrier.canShip(package)
        result.add(carrier)
return result
```

A carrier's canShip method might look like...

```
function canShip(package)
    return weightRule.Applies(package)
        and heightRule.Applies(package)
        and hazmatRule.Applies(package)
```

and the weightRule might look like...

```
function Applies(package)
    return package.weight < 70.0
```

Comment: thx for ur explaination